# SQL pivot nested

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, pivot

I am using Sql Server 2008 R2. My work is regarding Business Intelligence and Reporting.
Now I have a table as  below.

```
 declare @t table(  
 prod_type NVARCHAR(20),  
 WEEK   NVARCHAR(20),  
 COD_ACCT NVARCHAR(20),  
 BBH NVARCHAR(20)  
 );

 INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('Salary',   '41306',    '12313',    'Vikas'),  
 ('Salary', '41306',    '311',  'Ramesh'),  
 ('Salary', '41306',    '55',   'Vicky'),  
 ('Salary', '41306',    '44',   'Vicky'),  
 ('Salary', '41313',    '33',   'Vikas'),  
 ('Salary', '41313',    '22',   'Vikas'),  
 ('Salary', '41313',    '11',   'Ramesh'),  
 ('Salary', '41313',    '99',   'Vicky'),  
 ('Salary', '41320',    '88',   'Vicky'),  
 ('Salary', '41320',    '76',   'Vikas'),  
 ('Salary', '41320',    '545',  'Ramesh'),  
 ('Savings',    '41306',    '3',    'Vicky'),  
 ('Savings',    '41306',    '27',   'Ramesh'),  
 ('Savings',    '41306',    '324',  'Ramesh'),  
 ('Savings',    '41306',    '887',  'Vikas'),  
 ('Savings',    '41313',    '998',  'Vicky'),  
 ('Savings',    '41313',    '6754', 'Vikas'),  
 ('Savings',    '41313',    '3457', 'Ramesh'),  
 ('Savings',    '41313',    '5434', 'Vicky'),  
 ('Savings',    '41320',    '6554', 'Ramesh'),  
 ('Savings',    '41320',    '3322', 'Ramesh'),  
 ('Savings',    '41320',    '6542', 'Vikas')  
 ;
```

Now I want output in following format-

```
           Salary                          ST            Savings              STT  GT

Row Labels  01-Feb-13 08-Feb-13 15-Feb-13      01-Feb-13 08-Feb-13 15-Feb-13    
Ramesh        1        1           1       3      2       1          2          5    8  
Vicky         2        1           1       4      1       2          0          3    7
Vikas         1        2           1       4      1       1          1          3    7 
Grand Total   4        4           3       11     4       4          3         11   22
```

Note- ST= Salary Total ,STT= Saving Total ,GT= Grand Total (as Obtained in Pivot in Excel)

What  I do now is take table into Excel and Make a pivot as such with COUNT of  COD_ACCT in  Values   in Excel and BBH in Row and Prod_type and week in Columns  in Pivot in Excel.

Can I do that same in  TSql. It will save me all of that Pivot hassle.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Please suggest any terse SQL like PIVOT or CUBE syntax and any other syntax well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function as well as [`GROUPING SETS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in SQL Server 2008+.

Your code would be similar to this:

```
select 
  case when bbh is null then 'Grand Total' else bbh end bbh,
  sum([Salary_2013-02-03]) [Salary_2013-02-03], 
  sum([Salary_2013-02-10]) [Salary_2013-02-10], 
  sum([Salary_2013-02-17]) [Salary_2013-02-17],
  sum([Salary_2013-02-03]+[Salary_2013-02-10]+[Salary_2013-02-17]) ST,
  sum([Savings_2013-02-03]) [Savings_2013-02-03],
  sum([Savings_2013-02-10]) [Savings_2013-02-10], 
  sum([Savings_2013-02-17]) [Savings_2013-02-17],
  sum([Savings_2013-02-03]+[Savings_2013-02-10]+[Savings_2013-02-17]) STT
from 
(
  select 
    prod_type +'_'+
    convert(varchar(10), cast(cast(week as int) as datetime), 120) week, 
    cod_acct, 
    bbh
  from t
) src
pivot
(
  count(cod_acct)
  for week in ([Salary_2013-02-03], [Salary_2013-02-10], 
               [Salary_2013-02-17], [Savings_2013-02-03],
               [Savings_2013-02-10], [Savings_2013-02-17])
) piv
group by grouping sets((bbh), ())
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/19086/44).

This gives the result:

```
|         BBH | SALARY_2013-02-03 | SALARY_2013-02-10 | SALARY_2013-02-17 | ST | SAVINGS_2013-02-03 | SAVINGS_2013-02-10 | SAVINGS_2013-02-17 | STT |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      Ramesh |                 1 |                 1 |                 1 |  3 |                  2 |                  1 |                  2 |   5 |
|       Vicky |                 2 |                 1 |                 1 |  4 |                  1 |                  2 |                  0 |   3 |
|       Vikas |                 1 |                 2 |                 1 |  4 |                  1 |                  1 |                  1 |   3 |
| Grand Total |                 4 |                 4 |                 3 | 11 |                  4 |                  4 |                  3 |  11 |
```

Comment: @VivekSingh I am glad it is working for you.  If you found this answer helpful, then be sure to accept it via the checkmark to the left of it.  It will let future visitors know that the question was answered and you will get site rep for accepting. :)